# kiescanner does not detect updated kjars at remote maven nexus repository

Tags: maven, drools

I have a spring-boot  application (myapp) with drools the kie-ci module enabled (the drools version i use i the 7.13.0.Final).
I also host my kjars to a remote nexus maven repository.

KieScanner is not fully operative with remote nexus repository.

At the time of project building for first time, all the κjars are detected and downloaded in my local maven repo but when myapp is running the remote updated kjars are not detected by kiescanner.

When i manually delete the local kjars from the .m2 repository, then the latest kjars are downloaded locally and kiescanner detects them.

Seems to be more a maven issue than a drools issue.

My settings.xml maven file is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-releases</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>http:///XXX.XXX.X.ΧΧ:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>myprofile</id>
      <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://XXX.XXX.X.ΧΧ:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
      </repositories>
     </profile>
   </profiles>

</settings>
```

and i execute myapp by the following format:

```html
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=myprofile  target/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

How i can make myapp to detect remote nexus updated kjars dynamically?

Thank you very much for you time!

Comment: were you able to solve this?